# What does "(deleted)" in the 'Votes' tab in the profile page mean?

Tags: support, closed-questions, profile-page

I was going through the 'Votes' tab of my profile when I noticed this:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

I found out that every question that I have a close vote on and is closed currently has "(deleted)" under it. [Here is the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427560/which-languages-among-thesec-java-and-c-are-best-to-consume-a-restful-web-ser) from the image above if anyone is interested.

What does "(deleted)" mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The vote is no longer *in progress*; the question has either been closed, or the votes have been deleted after expiring.

When that happens, the vote is marked as deleted, all that remains is the vote log.

For the specific question you link to, the question was put on hold, so the close votes on the post have been deleted as they are no longer waiting for other close votes to accumulate.

Comment: Note that votes that ages away after 14 days doesn't produce this, as the user can vote again.

Comment: It seems that when you retract the vote the "deleted" is also displayed.

Comment: What it _looks like_ is that the question has been deleted.   It's easy to establish that it hasn't, of course, by clicking on the link, but it confused me enough to come here and write the same question as the OP above, and hence to find this.    Is there any prospect of that word being changed?  (I'm not going to ask that question formally if there's none!)

Comment: @GreenAsJade: No idea if there is; why not create a [meta-tag:feature-request] post and see if others experience it as a problem too?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Because I am very bad at creating positively received feature-requests :( :(       http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295427  is my latest abject failure.

Comment: @GreenAsJade hrms, GEO is trolling there. I agree the FR is perhaps not needed though. The request itself is well enough written up!