# Should we have a specific reward (badge?) for rescuing a question from the CVQ

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I wonder if we could have a reward (aside from the personal satisfaction) for rescuing a question from the Close Vote Queue?

It probably needs some discussion as to what that exactly means, but I was thinking:

- Chose "Edit" on the CVQ on a question with negative votes
- Resulted in the question having positive votes and an accepted answer.

As well as just adding to the very few public rewards for participating in the CVQ, such a badge would be one small way of providing incentive to treat questions with care and nurture in the CVQ, rather than taking the easy path of hitting "close" each time....

Comment: "Has an accepted answer" is no argument for quality; askers of crappy questions routinely accept crappy answers.

Comment: @JoshCaswell furthermore, "having a positive score" is no argument for quality; answerers of crappy questions routinely upvote crappy questions.

Answer (score 4):

We do don't we?

The [Explainer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4368/explainer), [Refiner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4369/refiner) and [Illuminator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator) badges.

Comment: That goes quite close.   Arguably "close enough".   I hadn't noticed that one before.   I'm pondering whether it fully meets the intent of rewarding the action of resucing a _flagged_ question, and whether that nuance is important?